# ruby tk and fork with exit cause an abort: "[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue"

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fork, tk-toolkit

Working with ruby 1.9.3 with tk and I've found that I can't do a fork inside the mainloop that calls "exit" - I need to get out of the fork by doing something like exec().

Example program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new 

def doit
  unless fork
    puts "Inside the fork"
    exit  # This is where it falls apart
  end
end 

TkButton.new(root) {
  text 'go'
  command proc { doit }
}.pack

Tk.mainloop()
```

Press the button and we properly fork, but when fork calls 'exit' then we get:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
ruby: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
ruby: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

I've discovered that I can hack a workaround by using something like "exec('echo')" instead of the exit, but that's just plain silly.  What's going on that exit doesn't work?  Is there some way to call XInitThreads from ruby (this isn't jruby or fxruby) that I can use and will that help?

From my research so far, it seems that ruby and Tk are pretty broken the moment you introduce threads or forking, but I have not been able to find a clean way to deal with this problem.

Comment: What version of Tcl/Tk are you using?  It looks like this problem should be fixed in 8.6.5.

Comment: Good question - I have Tk 8.5 installed, but google doesn't seem to know of any way to get the version of Tk that ruby is using.

I tried building a new ruby with Tk 8.6 and ruby-build complained that 8.6 wasn't working with ruby (2.3.1)

Comment: I just tested with 8.6.6 and expect and the issue is not fixed.

Comment: See [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/ruby-tk-and-tk-8-6/232416/6) discussion regarding Ruby-Tk and Tk 8.6.

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists with any Tcl built with thread support.

You will have to restructure your program so that the Tcl/Tk processes are separate entities and do not get forked.

The gui will need to send any input commands to the appropriate ruby thread and the threads will need to send data to the gui to be displayed.

Comment: Can you give a citation for why I can't fork a tcl thread if I exit() before doing anything tk/tcl based?